# sed + how to remove the word if one of the characters in word contain "m" or "M"

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

How to remove the word if one of the characters in the word contains "m" or "M"?

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
 echo 6.5G 66.5m | sed -e 's/[m][M]//g'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sed command is

```
s/[m][M]//g
```

This will remove only the string `mM` from its input, because you've asked to match

- anything in the set `m`, followed by
- anything in the set `M`.

You probably meant to write `[Mm]` instead.  You can get the same effect by adding the `/i` option to the `s` command, though:

```
s/m//ig
```

Now this will remove all upper- or lower-case `m`s:

```
$ echo 6.5G 66.5m | sed -e s/m//ig
6.5G 66.5
```

Your question asks how to remove entire words containing this letter.  For that, we need to match any non-space characters before or after.  `[^ ]` matches a non-space character, and `[^ ]*` matches zero or more non-space characters, so we want

```
s/[^ ]*m[^ ]*//ig
```

Testing this:

```
$ echo 6.5G 66.5m | sed -e 's/[^ ]*m[^ ]*//ig'
6.5G
```

and

```
$ echo Five Merry Women went fishing | sed -e 's/[^ ]*m[^ ]*//ig'
Five   went fishing
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 6.5G 66.5m | sed -e 's/[[:space:]].*[mM]//g'
6.5G
```

Note that the "m" and "M" form one pattern - your (non-working) version looks for an "m" followed by an "M".

Comment: except that the OP said "How to remove the word", not just the letter

Comment: Uh, I missed that - discounted numbers from being in words. Updated, thanks!

Comment: what about "Merry" ?

Comment: I was only considering the OP's input. Not an excuse, though - slack on my part. A less naive solution would catch characters after the match, but before the next whitespace. I'd update my answer but there's a better answer provided (and I've voted for it).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to remove you can try this

```
[root@connect ~]# echo 6.5M 66.5m | sed -e 's/m//g' | sed -e 's/M//g'
6.5 66.5
```

Comment: except that the OP said "How to remove the word", not just the letter

Comment: @JeffSchaller made changes

Answer (score -2):

Try This it will Delete The line containg 'm' or 'M'

```
echo 6.5G 66.5m | sed "/[mM]/d"
```

Comment: except that the OP said "How to remove the *word*"